# Set-theoretical inequality

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, inequality

Let $G$ be a group and suppose $E \subseteq G$ finite and symmetric (i.e. $g^{-1} \in E$, for all $g \in E$) . Define $E^n=\lbrace g_1g_2...g_n \mid g_i \in E \rbrace$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For all $g \in G$, denote $gE^n=\lbrace gt \mid t \in E^n \rbrace$. Is there an elementary way to show that $$|gE^n \Delta E^n| \leq |E^{n+1}| - |E^n|,$$
where '$\Delta$' denotes the symmetric difference?

$\textbf{EDIT}$:

I misread the the question. It should be $g \in E$.

Comment: I can't make sense of this, because if $E$ is a subgroup, then $E^n = E$ for all $n$ and so $|E^{n+1}| - |E^n| = 0$.

Comment: It was something I came across while reading the following:http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~juschenk/files/Juschenko-Book-4.pdf, page 35

Comment: @NoahSchweber I wasn't really assuming that $E$ is a subgroup, I was just pointing out that the assertion is false in the case when $E$ is a subgroup.

Comment: @J.Bosser  In the paper you are linking to the element $g$ is assumed to lie in $E$,

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for the answer! I misread the proof. What a silly mistake, my bad!

Comment: @DerekHolt I edited my question. This gives you that $|gE^n \Delta E^n| = |gE^{n}| + |E^n| -2|gE^n \cap E^n| \leq |E^{n+1}| + |E^n| - 2|gE^n \cap E^n|$. How do you continue from that point?